# FAST_REFRESH=FALSE in .env file is not working (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am new to react. My app created with `create-react-app` is not refreshing automatically.

I created `.env` file in main directory but still no luck.

### .env

```
FAST_REFRESH=false
```

### Package.json:

```
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into this issue : https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9913

or this one https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/9884

One of the way of doing it is starting the app like so :

```
FAST_REFRESH=false yarn start
```

or

```
FAST_REFRESH=false npm start
```

Comment: Thanks It was working fine.